# Fixing memory management issues in iOS app

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I know there is been a lot asked questions about this topic, but before declaring it duplicate read my question, Thanks.

I am an `iOS` developer with mid-level experience, but fortunately or unfortunately never ran into any memory leaking issues like I am facing right now. I have given an app not written by me which has google maps integrated into it, it had lots of issue including memory leaks, App uses Delegate pattern, and I did fixed delegate classes with code like this

```
@objc protocol myDelegate { 
    // delegate stuff
}
class myClass: UICollectionView {
    weak var delegate: myDelegate? = .none
}
```

I read a lot about memory graph debugging, so I used it to find my leaks. now, sharing some date which I have collected using memory graph debugger
[this is the image where I found memory leak indications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhwxm.png), but strange thing is there is not a single indication about the files that have written by us, but all the indication showing files from core or the libraries that we are using, I did not understand that,
then I found [this, its a UserNotificationCenter block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHYQy.png), I saw in code that it never deallocate notifications that have been posted. Is that necessary to deallocate them, 
after all these things , app has CoreData entities and I found [this, these are all tables using in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMcRs.png), I failed to understand how can they be a memory leak, 
and finally these are [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh5tY.png) a whole block of malloc block, which I again do not know what does it means. does this have to do any thing with a memory leak,
below images shows memory consumption just switching from 2 or 3 screens, 
P.S these screens have `UICollectionViews` and `UITableViews` in them,
[just switched from home to one new screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK4gi.png), and [switched between 3 screens just once.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC5Az.png)
I hope I can get help from this platform. Thanks